# Pligg is built upon what framework, if any?

Tags: php, frameworks

I am trying to modify a Pligg site but the conventions sound too alien too me, So I am wondering which php framework, if any, should I known to start deciphering the Pligg templating language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pligg isn't built on any of the known php frameworks.

Comment: Alas! That explains the mess! Since apparently it uses Smarty, and smarty (as far as I know) is part of a php framework, I was hoping... Thanks man.

Comment: Smarty is a templating engine. A php framework may or may not use smarty(depending on its user),

Comment: You don't need any more tutorials than what's there. Besides, there's a forum.

Answer (score 1):

To be more exact, "Pligg uses a variation of the Smarty template engine, called Template Lite". ([reference](http://www.pligg.com/blog/707/how-to-design-a-pligg-template/)) However, I am still not sure how much different they are.